# Maven Archetypes & Project Structure

Tags: apache, maven, build-automation

Maven newmbie here. Been looking over the [docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html) at the official Maven site and am trying to understand the difference between a Maven **archetype** and the actual directory structure of a Maven-based project.

*Does an archetype dictate the project directory structure, or are they two separate concepts?* If they are different, then what sorts of things/behaviors does an archetype control?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The directory structure is dictated, as by "best practice". (One could use maven to create one's own archetype from an existing project though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All archetypes should share the same basic project directory structure.

Some archetypes will add directories that are specific to the nature of the project you are creating (i.e. a J2EE archetype might have an additional WebContent folder, a flex archetype might generate a flex source directory, etc...).

Additionally, archetypes will generate a basic POM including the plugins you need.

Answer (score 1):

A maven archetype is basically a reusable project template. Archetype can create a working Maven project with a proper directory structure and some sample code to get you up and running  quick. There is number of archetypes available to create various projects. For example you can create a basic web aplication or web application with SEAM support for JBoss server, etc.